Pull all date-containing cells from a table into a single sortable column
Solved thank to nkalvi! Here is the formula that worked to make a chronologically descending array instead of a table (modified slightly from the formula from nkalvi to remove duplicates):
=LET(
dates_, IF(ISBLANK(Dates[[1巡目]:[11巡目]]), NA(), Dates[[1巡目]:[11巡目]]),
no_dates, LAMBDA(row_,
    COUNTBLANK(INDEX(Dates[[1巡目]:[11巡目]], row_, )) = 11
),
loc_header, "名前",
date_header, "日付",
idx, SEQUENCE(ROWS(dates_)),
date_and_loc_0, REDUCE(
    {"Loc","Date"},
    idx,
    LAMBDA(acc,cur,
        IF(
            no_dates(cur),
            acc,
            LET(
                dates_to_col, TOCOL(INDEX(dates_, cur, ), 2),
                loc, INDEX(Dates[名前], cur, 1),
                loc_col, EXPAND(loc, ROWS(dates_to_col), , loc),
                VSTACK(acc, HSTACK(dates_to_col, loc_col))
            ))
    )
),
date_and_loc, DROP(date_and_loc_0, 1),
filtered_unique, SORT(FILTER(date_and_loc, ISNUMBER(INDEX(date_and_loc, , 1)))),
unique_loc_and_date, UNIQUE(filtered_unique, , TRUE),
loc_and_date, CHOOSECOLS(unique_loc_and_date, 2, 1),
sort_by_asc_loc_desc_date, VSTACK(
    HSTACK(loc_header, date_header),
    SORTBY(
        loc_and_date,
        INDEX(loc_and_date, , 1),
        ,
        INDEX(loc_and_date, , 2),
        -1
    )
),
sort_by_desc_date_asc_loc, VSTACK(
    HSTACK(date_header, loc_header),
    SORTBY(
        unique_loc_and_date,
        INDEX(unique_loc_and_date, , 1),
        -1,
        INDEX(unique_loc_and_date, , 2),
        1
    )
),
HSTACK(sort_by_asc_loc_desc_date, sort_by_desc_date_asc_loc))

ORIGINAL POST:
I have a table titled "Dates" containing 11 rows of date data. Sometimes, there will be multiple of the same date in more than one row. I want to pull every date to a single column (A1: 日付) in a table titled "Timeline". Every date from the Dates table should be listed and filterable/sortable. Beside each date (B1: 名前) should be the name of the facility that was visited on that date (pulled from the 名前 column in the Dates table). Hopefully using the MATCH function or other dynamic function to keep the columns filterable without breaking? I want to avoid using cell names (e.g., A1:E239) and instead pull the data dynamically using the column headers of the Dates table if possible.
Again, every date should be listed in the first column of the Timeline table (A1) and sortable ascending/descending to view each visit chronologically.
Is this possible? I have limited excel knowledge but usually can figure out how to do what I want with lots of searching and troubleshooting, but I can't seem to solve this.


What have you tried and where does it fail? Can you give examples with actual data?

And FWIW, you don't have a 'table'. This is a spreadsheet, not a database.

@JanDoggen, Create a table in Excel - Microsoft Support

@nkalvi It's a spreadsheet program, not a database. Which does not stop people from using it as such. Reminds me of the time I found a company using WordStar to store tabular data ;-)

@JanDoggen, I understood how you interpreted the term; I just wanted to point out that the use of term in this question's context was valid.

First, my apologies for any language errors due to OCR.

Here's a suggestion using formula only. Adding Sort/Filter to formula results is not possible (since you cannot change part of an array), so I've given a couple ways to get sorted results. If you want have Sort/Filter buttons, you need to copy the results elsewhere and add a table (losing dynamic updating).
Steps
Get a date-location array from Dates table:

For each row, get all non-blank dates as column
TOCOL(INDEX(dates_, cur, ), 2)
Add location column, setting the same location for each date
EXPAND(loc, ROWS(dates_to_col), , loc)
Remove duplicates

Then to get sorted results (as examples):

get location-date array by swapping the columns
Use SORTBY to sort by multiple columns

SORTBY function - Microsoft Support
Assuming you have Excel for Microsoft 365, enter following in the first cell for the result (A1 in the example):
=LET(
    dates_, IF(ISBLANK(Dates[[1巡目]:[11巡目]]), NA(), Dates[[1巡目]:[11巡目]]),
    no_dates, LAMBDA(row_,
        COUNTBLANK(INDEX(Dates[[1巡目]:[11巡目]], row_, )) = 11
    ),
    loc_header, "名前",
    date_header, "日付",
    idx, SEQUENCE(ROWS(dates_)),
    date_and_loc_0, REDUCE(
        {"Loc", "Date"},
        idx,
        LAMBDA(acc, cur,
            IF(
                no_dates(cur),
                acc,
                LET(
                    dates_to_col, TOCOL(INDEX(dates_, cur, ), 2),
                    loc, INDEX(Dates[名前], cur, 1),
                    loc_col, EXPAND(loc, ROWS(dates_to_col), , loc),
                    VSTACK(acc, HSTACK(dates_to_col, loc_col))
                )))
    ),
    date_and_loc, UNIQUE(DROP(date_and_loc_0, 1)),
    loc_and_date, CHOOSECOLS(date_and_loc, 2, 1),
    sort_by_asc_loc_desc_date, VSTACK(
        HSTACK(loc_header, date_header),
        SORTBY(
            loc_and_date,
            INDEX(loc_and_date, , 1),
            ,
            INDEX(loc_and_date, , 2),
            -1
        )
    ),
    sort_by_desc_date_asc_loc, VSTACK(
        HSTACK(date_header, loc_header),
        SORTBY(
            date_and_loc,
            INDEX(date_and_loc, , 1),
            -1,
            INDEX(date_and_loc, , 2),
            1
        )
    ),
    HSTACK(sort_by_asc_loc_desc_date, sort_by_desc_date_asc_loc)
)



Firstly, let me say that you are amazing. As someone who uses Excel only with lots of trial and error tinkering, this feels like magic, haha. I really appreciate your quick response with a thorough and functional formula (demonstrated with literally the same non-English data from my screenshot). The formula as is did not remove duplicates—it listed two of each name. However, I was able to achieve that with the help of ChatGPT which added a line for filtered_unique and unique_loc_and_date. Thank you again!

I don't have enough reputation to upvote your comment because I made this account to ask this question, but 1000 times "This answer was useful." Thank you again.

@user2289877, It's my pleasure and I'm glad to hear that it is helpful!
